Styling gv with .Xdefaults
I am trying to style gv using my ~/.Xdefaults file, its working fine for other applications, but not for gv, I am able to set the background to gray:
gv*background: gray
But this gives all elements that gray background, and that is not what I want, the "canvas" or paper is also gray for instance. I would like to apply my "styling" more precisely, but I can not find any information about the resources related to the look and feel of gv, I have read the gv manual, and the info and man page, I have looked in ~/.gv but so far, nothing useful
If I use editres (X11) to try and see the resources and widgets used by gv, I only get widgets related to the menu, not the rest of the application. I have also tried xprop, etc.
editres output:
GV  gv
    VendorShellExt  shellext
    Aaa  control
        MButton  fileButton
            SimpleMenu  menu
                ThreeD  threeD
                SmeBSB  open
                SmeBSB  reopen
                SmeBSB  savepos
                SmeBSB  update
                SmeLine  line
                SmeBSB  printAllPages
                SmeBSB  printMarkedPages
                SmeBSB  saveAllPages
                SmeBSB  saveMarkedPages
                SmeLine  line
                SmeBSB  copyright
                SmeLine  line
                SmeBSB  quit
        MButton  stateButton
            SimpleMenu  menu
                ThreeD  threeD
                SmeBSB  stop
                SmeBSB  dsc
                SmeBSB  eof
                SmeBSB  antialias
                SmeBSB  watchFile
                SmeBSB  size
                SmeLine  line
                SmeBSB  optionsgv
                SmeBSB  optionsgs
                SmeBSB  optionsfs
                SmeBSB  optionssetup
                SmeLine  line
                SmeBSB  presentation
        MButton  pageButton
            SimpleMenu  menu
                ThreeD  threeD
                SmeBSB  next
                SmeBSB  redisplay
                SmeBSB  prev
                SmeLine  line
                SmeBSB  center
                SmeLine  line
                SmeBSB  current
                SmeBSB  odd
                SmeBSB  even
                SmeBSB  unmark
        MButton  orientationButton
            SimpleMenu  menu
                ThreeD  threeD
                SmeBSB  automatic
                SmeLine  line
                SmeBSB  portrait
                SmeBSB  landscape
                SmeBSB  upsidedown
                SmeBSB  seascape
                SmeLine  line
                SmeBSB  swap
        MButton  pagemediaButton
            SimpleMenu  menu
                ThreeD  threeD
                SmeBSB  automatic
                SmeLine  line
                SmeBSB  BBox
                SmeBSB  Letter
                SmeBSB  Legal
                SmeBSB  Statement
                SmeBSB  Tabloid
                SmeBSB  Ledger
                SmeBSB  Folio
                SmeBSB  Quarto
                SmeBSB  10x14
                SmeBSB  14x24
                SmeBSB  Executive
                SmeBSB  A3
                SmeBSB  A4
                SmeBSB  A5
                SmeBSB  B4
                SmeBSB  B5
        MButton  processButton
        MButton  scaleButton
            SimpleMenu  menu
                ThreeD  threeD
                SmeBSB  Natural size
                SmeBSB  Pixel based
                SmeLine  line
                SmeBSB  Fit height to window
                SmeBSB  Arbitrary magnification
                SmeBSB  Fit width to window
                SmeBSB  Fit to window
                SmeBSB  0.100
                SmeBSB  0.125
                SmeBSB  0.250
                SmeBSB  0.500
                SmeBSB  0.707
                SmeBSB  1.000
                SmeBSB  1.414
                SmeBSB  2.000
                SmeBSB  4.000
                SmeBSB  8.000
                SmeBSB  10.00
        Button  nextPage
        Button  prevPage
        Button  toggleCurrent
        Button  toggleEven
        Button  toggleOdd
        Button  unmarkAll
        Button  printMarked
        Button  printAll
        Button  saveMarked
        Button  saveAll
        Button  openFile
        Button  autoResize
        Button  redisplay
        MButton  titleButton
            SimpleMenu  menu
                ThreeD  threeD
                SmeBSB  title
        MButton  dateButton
            SimpleMenu  menu
                ThreeD  threeD
                SmeBSB  date
        Label  locator
        Frame  pannerFrame
            Composite  panner
                Label  slider
        Frame  newtocFrame
            Clip  newtocClip
                Aaa  newtocControl
                    Vlist  newtoc
        Scrollbar  newtocScroll
        Frame  viewFrame
            Clip  viewClip
                Aaa  viewControl
                    Ghostview  page
    TransientShell  fileSelPopup
        VendorShellExt  shellext
        FileSelection  fileSel
            Button  rescan
            MButton  filters
                SimpleMenu  menu
                    ThreeD  threeD
                    SmeBSB  None
                    SmeBSB  *.*ps* *.pdf* no .*
                    SmeBSB  *.*ps* no .*
                    SmeBSB  *.pdf* no .*
                    SmeBSB  no .*
            MButton  dirs
                SimpleMenu  menu
                    ThreeD  threeD
                    SmeBSB  Home
                    SmeBSB  Tmp
                    SmeBSB  /usr/doc
                    SmeBSB  /usr/local/doc
            Button  button1
            Button  button2
            Frame  pathframe
                Text  pathtext
                    AsciiSrc  textSource
                    AsciiSink  textSink
            Frame  filterframe
                Text  filtertext
                    AsciiSrc  textSource
                    AsciiSink  textSink
            Frame  topframe
                Clip  topclip
                    Aaa  topaaa
                        Vlist  list
            Scrollbar  subscroll
            Frame  subframe
                Clip  subclip
                    Aaa  subaaa
                        Vlist  list
            Scrollbar  curscroll
            Frame  curframe
                Clip  curclip
                    Aaa  curaaa
                        Vlist  list


Can you give an example of a widget that you can't locate via editres or can't change the background color of? Note that editres lets you dump the widget tree to a file.

I have added the output of editres :)

Thanks. But what is it you want to change the color of?

I would like the basic interface to be gray, but I would like the "canvas" or paper to remain white, if I do gv*background: gray, then every widget is gray, including the "paper"

Using strace on gv shows that is opens the application defaults file /usr/share/gv/gv_system.ad, on my system. In there we can see
GV*Ghostview.background:        white
GV*Ghostview.foreground:        black

The class GV is less specific than the name gv, so setting gv*background: gray overrides it.
Simply add gv*Ghostview.background: white or use GV instead of gv in your original setting.

If you want all but the viewFrame to have a gray background, you can do:
gv*background: gray
gv*viewFrame*background: white

In your widget tree, that's:

GV  gv
[...]
        Aaa  control
                [...]
                Frame  viewFrame
                        Clip  viewClip
                                Aaa  viewControl
                                        Ghostview  page
[...]


(gv.control.viewFrame). You can be even more specific with gv.control.viewFrame.viewClip.viewControl.page, which leaves the controls gray in there. Compare:
 

I have tried setting:
gv.control.viewFrame.viewClip.viewControl.page: white
gv.control.viewFrame.viewClip.viewControl.page.background: white
gv*control*viewFrame*viewClip*viewControl*page: white
gv*control*viewFrame*viewClip*viewControl*page.background: white
None of them seems to work, I have reloaded my .Xdefaults file

Does gv -xrm 'gv*background: gray' -xrm 'gv*viewFrame*background: white' work for you? Note that ~/.Xdefaults (or rather ~/.Xdefaults-hostname) is meant to be read by applications on start-up. Though you can load the resources defined there in the X server you're connecting to as well with xrdb.

Yes, gv -xrm ... does work, I will try to restart X

What's the output of xrdb -q | grep -i background?

gv*background: gray
gv*control*viewFrame*viewClip*viewControl*page*background: white
The more specific setting, to avoid the context menu being white, does not work, though

Works for me whether those 2 resources are passed via -xrm or loaded by gv from ~/.Xdefaults-$HOSTNAME or stored in the X server with xrdb -merge. Are there possibly conflicting resources in your ~/.Xdefaults-$HOSTNAME or in the output of xrdb -q?
